# Protecting a Subdomain with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, wamp, subdomain

I have my own server and do everything on my end as much as possible for a gaming community (in order to keep overhead down).  This includes hosting the website myself with WAMP and Windows 10. Let's say I have a domain. I'm using a REST server for .. stuff. I need to provide access to the REST server via a Web Control Panel that uses a chunk of complicated PHP and Javascript noise to work. The only way to run it is through the server (obviously) which means it needs it's own virtual host to operate (I think. It doesn't work if I just use PHP Include). So I created a subdomain (rest.domain.com) and plugged that into the src for an iframe that I put on a webpage that is password protected. The only problem I'm facing right now is that anyone can go to rest.domain.com and go right around the paltry Wordpress security and mess about with my stuff.

I'm open to either

1. Blocking direct URL access and including some fancy code so only the iFrame can get to it.
2. Passwording the SubDomain and just giving my REST users the rest.domain.com url.
3. Something entirely different that I didn't know existed.

What should I do?

**EDIT:1**

So, we've gotten to the point where we're using an .htaccess file to restrict the subdomain with a login/password.  I've created the .htaccess file in the directory of the REST files and created an .htpasswd file.

I am now receiving 500ISE errors.
I have gone down through 3 Google Search pages trying to research the issue and have made dozens of edits to my .htaccess file to make it work.  Without the htaccess, the REST server can be accessed without restriction.  The error is in the .htaccess file.  Here is what my .htaccess file looks like upon giving up on this for the evening:

Messing around with this for hours and have gone down 3 Google Pages, opening and researching every single hit (most are on SO) and still stuck on a 500 Internal Server Error.  This is where I'm sitting at right now with my htaccess file and this is where I'm giving up for the night:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Locked"
AuthUserFile o:\..\..\..\..\.htpasswd
Require valid-user

SetEnvIf Host rest.domain.com !secure_content

Order Allow,Deny
Allow env secure_content
Deny From All

Satisfy Any
```

**EDIT:1.1**

So, instead of giving up (because I ain't no quitta!) I've started noticing a trend from a few other sites that using a far less complicated .htaccess than the "instructional" I originally found.  I went ahead and commented out the following lines:

```
#SetEnvIf Host rest.radio-takeover.com !secure_content

#Order Allow,Deny
#Allow env secure_content
#Deny From All

#Satisfy Any
```

It now appears to be working as intended.  Thank you, Jenny, for somewhat pointing me down the right path.

Comment: Show us your Virtual Hosts definitions

Comment: `#REST
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin [email]
 ServerName [sub.domain.com]
 ServerAlias [sub.domain.com]
 ErrorLog "logs/wordpress-error.log"
 CustomLog "logs/wordpress-access.log" common
 DocumentRoot O:/../../../../rest
 <Directory  "O:/../../../../rest">
  AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

   This is just for the subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

iframe source page can easily be protected through php redirection. In that way if a user is logged in iframe will show. Direct access to the iframe will show forbidden. Also Check laravel middleware authcheck and role and permissions..

Comment: If you block direct access to the url how would you show iframe from that url to another site or page? you can simply use authcheck and redirect options in the head tag of your rest.domain.com and by doing this direct access to rest.domain.com will be locked. only logged in users will have direct access to subdomain page or iframe.

Answer (score 0):

If thats not what you asked then here is another option.

Create a .htaccess file in root folder of rest.domain.com and write "deny from all" in it.Hope you will get what you need.

Comment: There's no folder for rest.domain.com.  It's a subdomain registered with my DNS provider that points to myserverip:80 and the httpd-vhosts.conf file points incoming requests from that subdomain to the PHP Project that is the REST server.  Now, if you're talking about the actual PHP project folder that the REST server resides in, then I can put an .htaccess file in there, but if I do "deny from all" it won't work in the iframe, right?

Comment: Here's what I've done so far.
  1) Created an .htaccess and put it in the REST directiory
      It looks like this:
          `SetEnvIf Host rest.DOMAIN.com secure_content
           AuthType Basic
           AuthName "Locked"
           AuthUserFile \www\wordpress\REST\.htpasswd
           Require valid-user
           
           Order Allow,Deny
           Allow from all
           Deny from env=secure_content
           
           Satisfy Any`
  2) Created an .htpasswd file and used [This Tool](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/)

Comment: 3) It brings up the login prompt and I put it in but I'm getting a 500 ISE.  Going to keep playing with it.